# Do you have any sample code on how Karate interact with Desktop Application

Tags: karate

I am looking for some sample on how to initiate Winappdriver , desktop application and  provide input. I could not find any samples, Code I tried below,
* karate.configure ('driverTarget',{ type:'winappdriver' ,port:4723 , executable:'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Application Driver/WinAppDriver.exe'});
   * karate.start()
If i am able to start any application installed on computer using exec as below why do i need to initiate windriverapp,
 * karate.exec('C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/EXCEL.EXE')
  * robot { app: 'Excel', highlight: true }
   * robot.input('karate dsl' + Key.ENTER)

Answer (score 0):

The only example is [this one](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/windows/calc.feature) - also read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driver-types

```
Feature:

  Background:
    * def session = { desiredCapabilities: { app: 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App' } }

    Scenario:
      Given driver { type: 'winappdriver', webDriverSession: '#(session)' }
      And driver.click('One')
      And driver.click('Plus')
      And driver.click('Seven')
      When driver.click('Equals')
      Then match driver.text('@CalculatorResults') contains '8'
```

We are trying to make [`karate-robot`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot) as a better alternative, but it needs some community help and contribution.